# Data not displaying from the flask sqlalchemy database

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to display the data of a person that is inputted via a pop-up form. But for whatever reason, the data isn't showing up on the HTML page.

Here is the HTML code for the home page

```
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> -->
<!-- onclick="window.location.href='add-users'" -->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='add-users.css') }}" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- <h4><a href="/logout">Log out</a></h4> -->
    <h1>
      <div class="dropdown" style="position:absolute; top:80px; right:170px;">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ user.name }}
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;"href="/logout"><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Log Out</button></a>
        <!-- <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Switch Users</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button> -->
      </div>
    </div></h1>
    <h1><button style="position:absolute; top:80px; right:100px; text-decoration: none"title="Add people" class="button" data-modal="modalOne"><span style="font-size:36px;">&#8853;</span></button></h1>
      <div id="modalOne" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="contact-form">
            <a class="close">&otimes;</a>
            <form method="POST" action="/">
              <h2>Add person</h2>
              <br>
              <!-- 2 column grid layout with text inputs for the first and last names -->
              <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-outline">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-outline">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <!-- Email input -->
              <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="email" name="person_email" id="person_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            
              <!-- Address input -->
              <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="address" name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="city" name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="county" name="county" placeholder="County" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            
              <!-- Submit button -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=container>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      {% for item in user.person %}
        {{ item.first_name }}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
      let modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".button")];
      modalBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
          let modal = btn.getAttribute("data-modal");
          document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        };
      });
      let closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
      closeBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
          let modal = btn.closest(".modal");
          modal.style.display = "none";
        };
      });
      window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target.className === "modal") {
          event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
      };

    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the code for models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import null
from . import __innit__ # importing from the package (website) the db
from flask_login import UserMixin

db = __innit__.db
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False, nullable=False)
   # person_email = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False, nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False)
    county = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False)
    #image = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, default="default.jpg")
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    person = db.relationship("Person")
```

Here is the code for views.py

```
@views.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def home(new_person):
    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.form.get("first_name")
        last_name = request.form.get("last_name")
        person_email = request.form.get("person_email")
        company = request.form.get("company")
        address = request.form.get("address")
        city = request.form.get("city")
        county = request.form.get("county")

        print(f"The first name is {first_name}")

        if first_name == "":
            flash("First name field empty", category="error")
        elif last_name == "":
            flash("Last name field empty", category="error")
        elif person_email == "":
            flash("Email field empty", category="error")
        elif company == "":
            flash("Company field empty", category="error")
        elif address == "":
            flash("Address field empty", category="error")
        elif city == "":
            flash("City field empty", category="error")
        elif county == "":
            flash("County field empty", category="error")
        else:
            new_person = Person(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, person_email=person_email, company=company, address=address, city=city, county=county, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_person)
            db.session.commit()
            print("USER ADDED")
            flash("New person added", category="success")
            redirect(url_for("views.home"))
        
    return render_template("second-home.html", user=current_user, new_person=new_person)
```

By the way the statement print(f"THe first name is {first_name}") isn't working, meaning the form isn't being accessed however when I hit the submit button, the terminal outputs a POST request

Here is the HTML page in which the data should be shown

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to explicitly set the `id` value for each of the inputs in your modal. You have `name` specified, but I *think* id is a more stable option when collecting form data.

If you're running this locally in dev mode (via terminal/cmd line) I would absolutely suggest throwing a `breakpoint()` in before `print(f"The first name is {first_name}")` and look at what values `request.form` actually returns.

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean, can you please clarify it?

Also, the name variable is just the username of the current user, it is independent of the form